# My ZFS dataset is gone after system upgrade/reboot (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I did recently upgrade my little NAS to ubuntu 14.04 and initially everything worked fine.
I'm used to re-import my ZFS pools after restarts and so it was no surprise when the mount point was gone after a restart 2 days ago.
But this time i was not able to re-import it and when i started looking closer the whole ZFS dataset disappeared too and i start to run out of ideas what to try (as do the google results i find).

$ zpool list or zpool status
no pools available

$ zfs list
no datasets available

$ ls /dev/disk/by-id/
... disks as i have used them in my config ...none missing

Everything was working fine before a reboot 2 days ago, and before that reboot i did run some upgrades including the kernel (standard upgrade via apt).
Re-installing/further upgrading or going back to previous versions (selected in grub) all did not help.

It would be really cool to get it back running, especially since i switched to ZFS for its promised reliability. The nice data redundancy does not help me if the whole storage disappears out of nowhere...

Any ideas?

Comment: going through all the possible steps again today i got a nice surprise as "zpool import" suddenly did show my pools again, and i was able to import them.
i still have no idea why or what was going on as i'm quite sure i tried that before - several times even. without luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same Problem. 
Doing

```
apt-get install ubuntu-zfs zfsutils
```

and rebooting solved it for me. 
For some Reasons ubuntu did not update all zfs-packages.
You can see if this is the case at the end of apt-get update output (packages held back)